# Is there a performance cost to autobox a primitive literal?

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing

Say I have the following code:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = ...
map.put("foo", true);
```

Theoretically, `true` will have to be autoboxed, resulting in a slight performance hit versus inserting `Boolean.TRUE`. But since we're dealing with a literal value, is it possible for the compiler to replace the primitive literal with a boxed literal so there's no extra runtime overhead?

Before anyone attacks me, I would generally opt for the primitive literal for the sake of code clarity, even if there was a tiny performance cost. This question is mostly theoretical.

Comment: the key to understanding any performance related question will always start with a test. To improve your question, show a timing test that gives results of a performance analysis. For instance, you could write a timed for-loop that puts 100K entries into a map and prints how long it took, and do the same for different arguments to `map.put`

Comment: You could use a `Boolean` constant; `map.put("foo", Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know. My question is whether it would help at all.

Comment: @assylias this is a question tailor made for you to answer; by showing the byte code.

Comment: @bohemian no bytecode analyser on my mobile - such a shame...

Comment: @assylias I'm mobile too :( I've considered creating an app to compile and run java - and why not show byte code too.

Comment: @shmosel an alternative is also to use a static import and replace `true` with `TRUE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a small performance hit. In order to box a primitive, the wrapper type's `valueOf()` method is used. Because this is such a simple method for `Boolean` (`return x ? TRUE : FALSE;`), a JIT might be able to effectively inline the result; currently the Java compiler, however, does not. (Use of `valueOf()` isn't required by the JLS, so an optimization for `Boolean` could be introduced.)

For other types, it's more complicated. For example, `Integer` returns cached instances for values near zero, and creates new instances for bigger values. Optimizations can still be performed, but allocating a new instance will always take some time.

---

In response to comments, let me focus on what I took to be the key point of the question:

> since we're dealing with a literal value, is it possible for the compiler to replace the primitive literal with a boxed literal

Yes, it is *possible,* but *no*, the Oracle `javac` compiler does not do this.

Does it matter? No, the performance hit for boxing to `Boolean` is infinitesimal; boxing `boolean` using the same `valueOf()` technique as other primitives is a safe and sane choice for the compiler.

Comment: I would be surprised if the JIT weren't able to inline that and make both options essentially equivalent. Your first sentence is maybe too categorical...

Comment: @assylias I would be surprised too, but would that happen on the first run? Even if it did, would that optimization process take extra time compared to code that used `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true`?

Comment: I think the key point is that the main performance hit arises whenever a *new object* must be allocated.  In the case of Boolean.valueOf(), a new object is never allocated.  The code really ought to make use of the class constant Boolean.TRUE, instead of the boolean primitive literal, but I would expect the actual performance difference between the two in this case to be immeasureably small,